# Detecting changes in 2 arrays of lines and highlight differences?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, text, richtextbox

Basically I got these 2 arrays of lines with text.

I want to compare these 2 arrays and highlight the differences. These arrays are rather big as I have some huge text files in there.

Any help on approaching this problem is welcome.

Regards

Comment: What have you tried? Also, in which language you have the problems: C# or Java?

Comment: 2 arrays of lines with text seems ambiguous to me . . Post some code and be more clear

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind of variation on the algo used to do genome sequence alignments. Essentially, you are looking to find the differences in two strings, store them in a place as diff 1, diff 2 and so on?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304772/DNA-Sequence-Alignment-using-Dynamic-Programming-A

I hope I haven't guessed your requirements wrong.:)

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly hard problem to solve, and it's called the "Longest common subsequence problem". I could try and describe it, along with a solution, but I will just point you at wikipedia for both, as I just looked at the article and someone's done a really good job.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem